# Sitecore: Change text colour on content tree node?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is it possible to change the colour of the text / name on the content tree of Sitecore based on a workflow state?

Am I right in thinking this could be done by the workflow modifying the "appearance, style" value on the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that should be done. It you set the value of the "style" field in the appearance tab to "COLOR:red;" the item name in the contenttree will be shown in a red font. It should also be possible to change the font, font style, size and other effects like bold/italic.

To achieve this you need to write a custom workflow action that sets the style property.

Comment: This IS interesting, had somehow missed this completely. Is there any appropriate event to look in order to change the style when the tree is rendered? I'd like to, for example change the style based on a field value.

Comment: I have seen this being done before but I had no idea how they did it, oh so easy. Thanks!

Comment: @andreasordell I'm not sure if this is possible, you might want to check out the the  processors in the renderContentEditor-pipeline

 <renderContentEditor>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor, Sitecore.Client"/>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderStandardContentEditor, Sitecore.Client"/>
      </renderContentEditor>